# Shimano FC-MT610 12-speed 30T crankset substitute

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, crankset, chainring, compatibility

I have a Shimano FC-MT610 12-speed 30T crankset and wish to go to a crankset with more teeth for flatter terrain. Shimano offers a 34T version.

Is there a higher tooth crankset compatible with a 96mm BCD? Shimano or other brands?

Comment: Search on any online bike store. Theres many non Shimano 96mm BCD + 12 Speed chainrings listed. Some brands go up to 40T. Just remember you'll be sacrificing climbing ability with more teeth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many options available from different brands. One way to do it is to keep your current cransket and only replace the chainring which would be more affordable than replacing the whole crankset.

Things to keep in mind when selecting a new chainring:

1. The spider of the FC-MT610 has **4 bolts** and the pattern is **asymmetric**. Asymmetric means that the bolts are not equally spaced around the circle they form.
2. For a BCD of **96mm**, chainrings with 5 bolt also exist. Of course, they won't be compatible with the FC-MT610.
3. Since the FC-MT610 has a single chainring, make sure you get one made specially for this configuration. They usually have a **narrow wide** tooth pattern that helps with chain retention.
4. Chainrings can also be **elliptical** (oval) instead of **round**. They can help provide more consistent power when pedalling.
5. Your **frame** may limit the size of the chainring, either because of its chain guard or other factors.
6. You also need to make sure your **chain** is compatible.
7. The number of **speeds** is usually pretty wide (e.g. from 9 to 12) but it is always good to make sure.

As you mentioned, Shimano offers a 34T chainring for the FC-MT610. Other third party chainring manufacturers such as [Black Spire](https://www.blackspire.com/) and [Wolf Tooth](https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/) have other options such as 36T or 38T.